# Xamarin Profiler in Visual Studio 2019 Mac

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-profiler

I want to use Xamarin profiler in Visual Studio 2019 Mac. I found its only available in enterprise edition. I want to try trial version of enterprise edition.

How to install trail version of enterprise edition in Mac? I went to this link but couldn't find one for mac. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

About [Profiler Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/profiler/?tabs=macos#profiler-support) of **Xamarin Profiler** :

[image]

> You will need to be [a Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/) to unlock this feature in either Visual Studio Enterprise on Windows or Visual Studio for Mac on a Mac.

Here not need to download a enterprise deition in Mac , VS for Mac has only a version to be downloaded . You not need to download another version of VS for Mac .

Just Download the **Profiler** install package for your platform:

- [macOS](https://dl.xamarin.com/profiler/profiler-mac-1.6.13-11.pkg)
- [Windows](https://dl.xamarin.com/profiler/XamarinProfiler.Windows.Installer.1.6.10-15.msi)

**That means** you need to use a **Visual Studio Enterprise subscriber** for vs for mac,and if you have purchased a Visual Studio Professional or Enterprise Subscription (Standard or Cloud), the license applies to Visual Studio for Mac as well. Standalone Licenses for Visual Studio Professional 2019 do not apply to Visual Studio for Mac.

Having a look at this : https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/mac/can-use-existing-visual-studio-license-mac/

Comment: I am not  Enterprise subscriber. I want to use the trail version of it. Is it possible

Comment: @KhimBahadurGurung Unfortunately , that's impossible . If answer be helpful , remember to mark it . Thanks in advance :-)